# What is the predicate for a macro in LISP

Tags: macros, lisp, predicate

Would somebody know what is the predictate to test if a symbol represents a macro in lisp ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [macro-function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_macro_.htm#macro-function):

```
CL-USER> (defmacro foo () ''foo)
FOO
CL-USER> (defun bar () 'bar)
BAR
CL-USER> (macro-function 'foo)
#<Compiled-function FOO Macroexpander #x187F0026>
CL-USER> (macro-function 'bar)
NIL
```